# 'Simple' problem. Delay not working?

Tags: servo

Servo goes to one end, and immediately travels back without a 2s delay inbetween. After it travels back there is a 2s delay before it loops. Why isn't there a 2s delay before the travel back?

```
Servo testservo;

void setup() {
    testservo.attach(9);
}

void loop() {  
    testservo.writeMicroseconds(700);
    delay(2000);
    testservo.writeMicroseconds(2300);
    delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: Because you have a slow servo that takes two seconds to go from one end to the other?  Try with a longer delay.

Comment: If that were true, I don't see why i'd be observing the servo 'stop' for 2s after the second position. I've tried longer delays. The effect is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your description (“Servo goes to one end, and immediately travels back without a 2s delay... After it travels back there is a 2s delay before it loops”) implies an overall cycle time of 2 seconds, which appears to be inconsistent with the overall 4-second cycle implied by the code shown.

Here are things you can do to debug the problem:

1. Turn on an LED before one `writeMicroseconds()` call, and turn it off before the other.  For example, add `pinMode(13, OUTPUT);` in `setup()`, and revise `loop()` as follows:

```
void loop() {  
    testservo.writeMicroseconds(700);
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    testservo.writeMicroseconds(2300);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    delay(2000);
}
```

This may allow you to find out which end the servo is going to.

2. Besides adding LED signals, try slightly-less extreme times in the `writeMicroseconds()` calls; eg 1000 and 2000 microseconds rather than 700 and 2300.
3. See if a neutral servo setting works, eg via code like the following.

```
enum { LEDpin=13, dtime=2000}
void stest(angletime, tHi, tLo) {
    testservo.writeMicroseconds(angletime);
    digitalWrite(LEDpin, HIGH);
    delay(tHi);
    digitalWrite(LEDpin, LOW);
    delay(tLo);
}
void loop() {
    stest(1000, dtime-50, 50); // Go CCW
    stest(1500, 50, dtime-50); // Middle
    stest(2000, 50, dtime-50); // Go CW
}
```

When this code runs, the LED should stay on about 2 seconds with the servo fully (or nearly so) counterclockwise.  Then the LED should blip and the servo should move to center position and stay there about 2 seconds.  Then the LED should blip and the servo should stay fully clockwise about 2 seconds.  This three-part cycle should repeat every six seconds.  If it works ok, then try modifying it, eg by changing 1000 us to 700, 2000 to 2300, etc, or by decreasing the `dtime` value to see how quickly the servo can respond, etc.

Comment: Something rather odd's that when i apply resistance to the servo with my fingers in the opposite direction of where it wants to go, the timing and all is fixed and it goes to every position as programmed. I'm clueless. Could the servo have a problem or something?

Comment: I just tried using another servo and everything's fine. What's wrong with the other servo? Am I able to fix it? :-(

Comment: I just tried powering my board not through my avr pocket programmer... Everything works fine now. Why is this so?

Comment: Insufficient power to the servo when powered like it was.